# C# extension using function Func as parameter

Tags: c#, functional-programming, extension-methods, func, chaining

***Please don't be confuse with the code, the code is wrong. Focused on the bold question below.***

I've been preparing to study functional programming and just so at least be ready for its prerequisites, I've been studying extensions, functions and lambda expressions.

This code below is NOT working I just thought this is how it should be coded:

Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int s = 10;
        int t = s.CreatedMethod(2, 3); // <-- the one that calls the extension
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static int RegularMethod(int v1, int v2)
    {
        return v1 * v2; // <-- I also wanted to multiply int 's' like this s*v1*v2
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int CreatedMethod(this int number, Func<int, int, int> fn) 
    { 
       // I'm expecting that the code here will read the 
       // RegularMethod() above
       // But I don't know how to pass the parameter of the function being passed
       return @fn(param1, param2)// <-- don't know how to code here ??
    } 
}
```

***As you can see, the CreateMethod extended my integer 's'. My plan is to pass the two parameters in CreateMethod() above and multiply those two parameters into 's'***

***In the example above, the answer should be 60.***

***Can you help me do it using extension?***

Comment: `Func<int, int, int>` accepts 2 input parameters and returns `int`. So to call it, yout should be `fun(param1, param2)`. Your extension just takes single parameter (except `fn`). So you need additional parameter in your `CreatedMethod`.

Comment: @DovydasSopa yes you're right I forgot to include it. But even if I do that. Where will I get the param1 and param2? look in the code.

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you want `Func<int, int, int>` in the first place. Why did you declare it that way if you intended to pass numbers?

Comment: Yeah I am wondering the same - why do you want to pass a function? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do `s.CreatedMethod(2, 3, RegularMethod)`? It's not clear why you'd want to do that unless `CreatedMethod` is doing something else too...

Comment: The code is wrong. It was said above. BY ANY MEANS. I just wanted to pass two parameters and use the extension method that's all. Basically I want a code. The code above is just the way I thought it should be.

Comment: @user1960948 it's difficult to give you correct code that does what you want if what you want is just "any working code." Can you see how that's a problem? You've given us code that doesn't work - we know it doesn't work and you know it doesn't work. That's fine. But without knowing what you want the code to **do**, how can we give you working code?

Comment: @AntP  I think I've said how I wanted the code to work, I even specify an expected output. I think the reason why we could put multiple answers in this stack are for questions who does have multiple ways to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension could look like this:

```
public static int CreatedMethod(this int number1, int number2, Func<int, int, int> fn) {
    fn(number1, number2);
}
```

And then call would be:

```
var s = 10;
var t = s.CreatedMethod(2, RegularMethod).
    CreatedMethod(3, RegularMethod);
```

This will first call `RegularMethod` with `10` and `2` and second time with `20` and `3`.

Additional way would be to use extension like

```
public static int CreatedMethod(this int number1, int number2, int number3, Func<int, int, int> fn) {
    fn(fn(number1, number2), number3);
}
```

And call like

```
var s = 10;
var t = s.CreatedMethod(2, 3, RegularMethod);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for but it doesn't make sense to pass a function as a parameter or maybe I'm just missing something. Anyway, it works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int s = 10;
        // the function we're passing as a parameter will multiply them
        // then return the result
        int t = s.CreatedMethod((param1, param2) => param1 * param2);
        // or you can use this since the method signature matches:
        // int t = s.CreatedMethod(RegularMethod);
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString()); // outputs "60"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int RegularMethod(int v1, int v2)
    {
        return v1 * v2; // <-- I also wanted to multiply int 's' like this s*v1*v2
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static int CreatedMethod(this int number, Func<int, int, int> fn)
    {
        return number * fn.Invoke(2, 3);
    }
}
```

Following up on OP's comment: If you don't want to hardcode the values then you'll need to change the `CreateMethod`'s signature to this:

```
public static int CreatedMethod(this int number, int val1, int val2, Func<int, int, int> fn)
```

then call `Invoke` like this:

```
fn.invoke(val1, val2)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to pass the `Func` as well as the `int` params... not sure why but there you go.

Comment: Hi Nasreddine this code --> fn.Invoke(2, 3) .. this is hardcoded right? I'll probably change it too.?

Comment: Yes they are hard coded unless you change your `CreateMethod` to something like `public static int CreatedMethod(this int number, int val1, int val2, Func<int, int, int> fn)` then call invoke with `fn.invoke(val1, val2)`